# Azure Active Directory Admin Center Devices Manage button greyed out

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In theory, I would like to manage our office devices from within the Azure Active Directory admin center at https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_Devices/DevicesMenuBlade/Devices/menuId/ 
However, when I select a device from the list the Manager button remains disabled. See screen shot:

[image]

I guess I'm missing something obvious but don't know what. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: Thanks, that covers it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you are an Intune administrator, you can manage devices marked as
>   **Microsoft Intune**. If the device is not enrolled with Microsoft Intune the "Manage" option will be greyed out.

[image]

[image]

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/device-management-azure-portal#manage-an-intune-device